# ActiveAdmin bcrypt users password on update or insert rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activeadmin, bcrypt

I am using ActiveAdmin as a admin panel, so I can create users through ActiveAdmin.

The Issue I'm having is when updating or inserting a users password, I need the value I entered in the ActiveAdmin form to hash the password with `bcrypt` and then work with rails `has_secure_password` authentication

Is there anyway I can get ActiveAdmin to include something like this?
`BCrypt::Password.create(params[:password])`

before saving to the database?

this is my `users.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
permit_params :email, :password_digest, :session_token, :session_key, 
:rank, :profileColour

index do
selectable_column
id_column
column :email
column :password_digest
column :session_token
column :session_key
column :rank
column :profileColour
actions
 end

filter :email
filter :session_token
filter :session_key
filter :rank
filter :profileColour

form do |f|
  f.inputs "Admin Details" do
  f.input :email
  f.input :password_digest
  f.input :rank
  end
  f.actions
end
```

end

Any advice would be greatly appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Why didn't you add `has_secure_password` to your model?

Comment: @fongfan999 It is in my model

Comment: Could you show me the form in the file `admin/users.rb`?

Comment: @fongfan999 Sure thing, I just edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `:password` instead of `:password_digest`

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Admin Details" do
  f.input :email
  f.input :password
  # f.input :password_confirmation
  f.input :rank
  end
  f.actions
end
```

---

Don't forget to [permit params](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html)

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params :email, :password, :rank
end
```

Comment: This worked huge thanks, you saved me a lot of time. I really appreciate it!